# 2.0 Equivalent of WCF Service

Tags: windows, wcf, service

Hosting a WCF Service Host in a Windows Service really seems to be quite a simple way to go to communicate with a running Windows Service...if you're running 3.0/3.5.

What the easiest way to get the same sorts of things out of the 2.0 Framework if that's what you're stuck with?

Answer (score 3):

You could host a [Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.80).aspx) service.

Answer (score 0):

[ASMX](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/308359) Web Service Hosted in IIS

Comment: You would then have to talk to the Windows service in question, so an ASMX web service wouldn't have accomplished anything, or am I wrong?